# Async Await Equivalent

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

When I run this code everything works fine:

```
public async void InvokePlugin(MyObject xTask)
{
    try
    {
        var hndlr = new TimeoutHandler(RunTask);
        var asyncResult = hndlr.BeginInvoke(xTask, null, new object());
        if (!asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(xTask.Timeout, false))
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Plugin didn't complete processing in a timely manner.");
        }
        hndlr.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle Exceptions
    }
}

private delegate void TimeoutHandler(MyObject xTask);
```

I want to update this code to use Async/Await.  I tried doing it like this:

```
public async void InvokePlugin(MyObject xTask)
{
    try
    {
        var runTask = Task.Run(() => { RunTask(xTask); });
        if (await Task.WhenAny(runTask, Task.Delay(xTask.Timeout)) == runTask)
        {
            // Task completed within timeout.
            // Consider that the task may have faulted or been canceled.
            // We re-await the task so that any exceptions/cancellation is rethrown.
            await runTask;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Plugin didn't complete processing in a timely manner.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle Exceptions
    }
}
```

...but it's not working.  Clearly I'm doing somethign wring.  It does call the RunTask Method and executes the first 2 lines fine but then it just ends and I can't seem to catch the exception in either the TaskRun method or code above.  All I see in the Output windows is "Program has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

If the experts out there can either point me to what I'm doing wrong or give me suggestions as to how I can catch the exception and handle it I would be very grateful.

Also if you feel I missed any important details please ask and I will update my question.

Usually I'd say if it works don't fix it but in this case I'm trying to rearchitect a bit to allow for some enhancements so here I am.

Comment: First thing I noticed, avoid signatures with `async void`. Use `async Task` instead so there is something to await for the caller. The only exception are event handlers in WPF and WinForms apps.

Comment: `await` is not the same as `Wait`. your original code is synchronous (`WaitOne`), so it's not eligible for converting to `async/await`.

Comment: 1) Change `async void` to `async Task`. 2) `await` the task, allowing `async` to grow. 3) In your `Main` method, call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the "top" task.

Comment: @StephenCleary Please post your comment as the solution and I will mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change `async void` to `async Task`. See my article on [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information.

After you do this, consume it asynchronously:

2. `await` the task, allowing `async` to grow.

`async` and `await` will naturally grow upward through your code base, until they reach `Main`, which cannot be `async`.

3. In your `Main` method, call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the "top" task.

[Blocking on asynchronous code is generally not a good idea](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but blocking on a single task in a Console app's `Main` method is an exception to that rule.

Comment: Why `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Wait()` or `.Result` ? Even though there may be *some* cases where it's more convenient, it appears in a *lot* of SO questions

Comment: Because `Wait` and `Result` wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`, complicating error handling code. `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` does not do that unnecessary wrapping.

Comment: The problem is that this has started appearing in a lot of unnecesary places, complicating the code. Instead of being a single call at the end of a console application, it started appearing in web applications, eg [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027847/code-never-get-past-call-to-eventprocessorhost-registereventprocessorasynclist), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947585/getasync-azure-call-no-result/42949748#42949748) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883020/get-token-from-oauth2-middleware)

Comment: Looking at the newest [posts that contain GetAwaiter()](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=getawaiter()) you'll see that `GetAwaiter()` is getting heavily misused

Comment: Yes, it's misused just like `Wait` and `Result` are.